# Pass a Parent Class to a method

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods

Hello everyone I have a method in a class that returns an instance of type children class:

```
class Test
{
    public Activos GetActivos(TiposActivo tipoActivo, int idActivo = 0)
    {
        switch (tipoActivo)
        {
            case TiposActivo.Cartera:
                Carteras carteras = new Carteras();
                return carteras;
            case TiposActivo.Clase:
                Clases clases = new Clases();
                return clases;
            case TiposActivo.Instrumento:
                Instrumentos instrumentos = new Instrumentos();
                return instrumentos;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }

}
```

Here, Carteras, Clases and Instrumentos are children of parent Activos.

Once returned, I want to operate on the object, but the code doesn't know if that object, of class Parent, is of type Son1, Child2, or Child3. How do I identify the type of class I'm operating on?

Comment: Why do you care? You should read up on. _polymorphism_, on _ virtual methods_ and on _pattern matching in C#_

Comment: You a wierd case where you have a Factory Function `GetActivos` yet at the same time a classs Heirarchy. This will not really work. | It is also not quite clear _why_ you have a Factory function in the first place - all you are doing is calling the constructor. So the function has no sensible purpose.

Comment: Actually, that kind of factory can be useful. Consider something like a drawing program (particularly if the components can be _plugged in_. The components provide an icon, a name and something that identifies them at the class level. When the user clicks and drags the icon onto the drawing surface, your factory  uses the identifier to figure out how to create the correct component. But, just about everything else is going to rely on virtual methods at that point

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks a lot. Flydog57 I'll do. Anyways  I care because they are not the same, if the method returns the parent class, I do not know what kind of object is. Or should I know?

Comment: @Christopher Hi Christopher, its just an example of what I'm trying. Its not the real code. Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: @Manuel The problem is, that this is basically the setup of a XY problem. You think that wierd "multi type factory method" is in any way the solution to the actuall problem. You should tell us the actuall, real problem is - so we can help you with that. This way we only risk wasting time while leading you further down the wrong path.

Comment: @Christopher Hi Christopher, the real problem is that I don't know how to operate with Inherintance and polymorphism. I came to C# from VBA, where I used to use Interfaces for doing this types of things. This is the problem: There are 3 tables in the Db with different names, and some differences between them, one of them has a field that other don't. But all of them share the same methods in the project.  Because of this, the Db should returns an IQueryable Object of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GetType` method:

```
        Activos act = GetActivos(TiposActivo.Cartera);

        string type = act.GetType().ToString();
```

Or:    (will also return true if act is a Class that inherits from `Carteras`)

```
        if (act is Carteras car)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Or:    (will only return true if act is of type `Carteras`. Not if it is a Class that inherits from `Carteras`)

```
        if (act.GetType() == typeof(Carteras))
        {
            Carteras car = (Carteras)act;
        }
```

Comment: You usually would write `if (act is Carteras car) { ... }`. This is much shorter and also catches the case where the type of act is in fact a subclass of Carteras.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that. I added it in above

Comment: While it works, one should not abuse of that. Generally better to rely on virtual functions instead.

Comment: Hi Kristian, but doing so I'ld have 3 fields to do the same. What I'm looking for is just one field for the three types, because actually, the are the same